# Updating a listctrl item

Tags: python, wxpython

so I got the thing to automatically add items to the list. my problem revolves now around updating entries given the code bellow.. when I select the item and try to update it *Via update via update button* all I get is this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\sad pROG\customer_app.py", line 97, in update_entry
entry = self.entrydict[self.list.GetItemText( long(self.index))]
KeyError: u'C0004'
```

replacing te getItemText() wit GetItem spawns this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\sad pROG\customer_app.py", line 97, in update_entry
    entry = self.entrydict[self.list.GetItem( long(self.index))]
KeyError: <wx._controls.ListItem; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'wxListItem *' at    0x25b7d60> >





from wx import *
import Customer as c
class CustomerMain ( wx.Frame ):

    def __init__( self, parent ):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = u"Customers", pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 517,486 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

        self.SetSizeHintsSz( wx.Size( -1,-1 ), wx.DefaultSize )

        bSizer3 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )


        # Create a customer
        self.cust = c.Customer()



        self.list = wx.ListCtrl( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize,wx.LC_REPORT )
        self.list.InsertColumn(0,"ID")
        self.list.InsertColumn(1,"First Name")
        self.list.InsertColumn(2,"Last Name")
        self.list.Bind(EVT_LIST_ITEM_SELECTED,self.GetSelectedItems)
        self.list.SetMinSize( wx.Size( 500,300 ) )
        self.list.SetMaxSize( wx.Size( 1000,800 ) )
        self.refresh_list(None)

        bSizer3.Add( self.list, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 5 )

        bSizer4 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.HORIZONTAL )
        self.m_button20 = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Add Customer", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.m_button20.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.add_entry)
        bSizer4.Add( self.m_button20, 1, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5 )

        self.m_button21 = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Update Record", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.m_button21.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.update_entry)
        bSizer4.Add( self.m_button21, 1, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL|wx.ALL, 5 )





        bSizer3.Add( bSizer4, 1, wx.EXPAND, 5 )

        self.SetSizer( bSizer3 )
        self.Layout()

        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )
        self.Show()

    def refresh_list(self, event):
        """Place the names of each CustomerEntry into the list"""

        index = 0
        self.entrydict = {}
        self.list.DeleteAllItems()
        for entry in self.cust.list_entries():
            self.list.InsertStringItem(index,entry.Cust_ID)
            self.list.SetStringItem(index,1,entry.F_Name)
            self.list.SetStringItem(index,2,entry.L_Name)
            self.entrydict[index] = entry
            index += 1


    def GetSelectedItems(self, event):
        """    Gets the selected items for the list control.
        Selection is returned as a list of selected indices,
        low to high.
        """
        selection = []
        self.index = self.list.GetFirstSelected()
        selection.append(self.index)
        while len(selection) != self.list.GetSelectedItemCount():
            self.index = self.list.GetNextSelected(self.index)
            selection.append(self.index)

        return self.index


    def add_entry(self, event):
       """Add a new entry to the Address cust"""
       # start out with blank, generic CustomerEntry
       entry = c.CustomerEntry("","","","","")
       self.endiag = CustomerDetail(self,entry)
       self.endiag.ShowModal()           



       self.cust.add_entry(entry.Cust_ID,
                            entry.F_Name,
                            entry.L_Name,
                            entry.Address,
                            entry.Cust_Stat )

       self.refresh_list(None)

    def update_entry(self, event):
       entry = self.entrydict[self.list.GetItemText( long(self.index))]
       self.endiag2 = CustomerDetail(self , entry)
       self.endiag2.ShowModal()

       self.cust.update_entry(entry.Cust_ID,
                            entry.F_Name,
                            entry.L_Name,
                            entry.Address,
                            entry.Cust_Stat )

       self.refresh_list(None)

def __del__( self ):
    pass


 class CustomerDetail ( wx.Dialog ):

    def __init__( self, parent, entry ):
            wx.Dialog.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 690,500 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE )

            self.entry = entry
            self.SetSizeHintsSz( wx.Size( 500,500 ), wx.DefaultSize )

            bSizer6 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

            gSizer6 = wx.GridSizer( 2, 2, 0, 0 )

            self.m_staticText5 = wx.StaticText( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"ID", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
            self.m_staticText5.Wrap( -1 )
            gSizer6.Add( self.m_staticText5, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5 )

            self.Cust_ID = wx.TextCtrl( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
            self.Cust_ID.SetMinSize( wx.Size( 200,15 ) )
            self.Cust_ID.SetMaxSize( wx.Size( 500,15 ) )

            gSizer6.Add( self.Cust_ID, 1, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL|wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5 )

            self.m_staticText6 = wx.StaticText( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"First Name", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
            self.m_staticText6.Wrap( -1 )
            gSizer6.Add( self.m_staticText6, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5 )

            self.F_Name = wx.TextCtrl( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
            self.F_Name.SetMinSize( wx.Size( 200,15 ) )
            self.F_Name.SetMaxSize( wx.Size( 500,15 ) )

            gSizer6.Add( self.F_Name, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wx.EXPAND, 5 )

            self.m_staticText7 = wx.StaticText( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Last Name", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
            self.m_staticText7.Wrap( -1 )
            gSizer6.Add( self.m_staticText7, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5 )

            self.L_Name = wx.TextCtrl( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
            self.L_Name.SetMinSize( wx.Size( 200,15 ) )
            self.L_Name.SetMaxSize( wx.Size( 500,15 ) )

            gSizer6.Add( self.L_Name, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5 )

            self.m_staticText8 = wx.StaticText( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Address", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
            self.m_staticText8.Wrap( -1 )
            gSizer6.Add( self.m_staticText8, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5 )

            self.Address = wx.TextCtrl( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
            self.Address.SetMinSize( wx.Size( 200,15 ) )
            self.Address.SetMaxSize( wx.Size( 500,15 ) )

            gSizer6.Add( self.Address, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL|wx.EXPAND, 5 )

            self.m_staticText12 = wx.StaticText( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Status", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
            self.m_staticText12.Wrap( -1 )
            gSizer6.Add( self.m_staticText12, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5 )


            stat_choices = ["Active","Inactive","Archived"]

            self.Cust_Stat = wx.ComboBox( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, stat_choices, 0 )
            self.Cust_Stat.SetMinSize( wx.Size( 200,15 ) )
            self.Cust_Stat.SetMaxSize( wx.Size( 300,15 ) )
            self.Cust_Stat.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.OnSelect)
            gSizer6.Add( self.Cust_Stat, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

            bSizer6.Add( gSizer6, 1, wx.EXPAND, 5 )

            bSizer13 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.HORIZONTAL )

            self.m_button24 = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"ok", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
            self.m_button24.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.ok)

            bSizer13.Add( self.m_button24, 1, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5 )

            self.m_button25 = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"cancel", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
            self.m_button25.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.closeDial)

            bSizer13.Add( self.m_button25, 1, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5 )

            bSizer6.Add( bSizer13, 1, wx.EXPAND, 5 )

            self.SetSizer( bSizer6 )
            self.Layout()

            self.Centre( wx.BOTH )

    def OnSelect (self, event):
        self.Cust_Stat.GetValue()



    def closeDial(self,event):

        self.Destroy()


    def ok(self, event):
        self.entry.set_details( str(self.Cust_ID.GetValue()),
                            str(self.F_Name.GetValue()),
                            str(self.L_Name.GetValue()),
                            str(self.Address.GetValue()),
                            str(self.Cust_Stat.GetValue()) )
        self.Destroy()


        def __del__( self ):
             pass                
def main():


ex = wx.App()
    CustomerMain(None)
    ex.MainLoop()    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Dunno what in the world the error means. any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.To get the list of selected items in ListCtrl, there is a function `getListCtrlSelection` in `wx.lib.mixins.listctrl`, so your `GetSelectedItems` method can be rewritten as

```
def GetSelectedItems(self, event):
    from wx.lib.mixins.listctrl import getListCtrlSelection
    self.index = getListCtrlSelection(self.list)
    return self.index
```

2.`self.index` is a list of indices, and `ListCtrl.GetItemText` needs one index as an input, so to get a list of selected items you can use list comprehension:

```
items = [self.list.GetItemText(i) for i in self.index]
```

Then you can get the entries from `self.entrydict` based on what you have got from `self.list`:

```
entries = [self.entrydict[item] for item in items]
```

Answer (score 0):

> Python raises a KeyError whenever a dict() object is requested (using
>   the format a = adict[key]) and the key is not in the dictionary.

[Doc on Keyerror is here.](http://wiki.python.org/moin/KeyError)

So most probably, `self.list.GetItemText( long(self.index))` is ne key in your `self.entrydict`. Can you check that with `print()` statements ?

Comment: Soooo Any work arounds for me getting the index of the currently selected item in a listctrl if such is the case?